# Message Format in WebService

Tags: web-services

What is meant by Message Format in WebService 
I have been told that Message Format can be of two styles (RPC / Document )

Please tell me what is meant by Message Format and how it is actually related to the Web services ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does [RPC/Literal and Freedom of Choice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996466.aspx) help? or [Which style of WSDL should I use?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/)

Answer (score 1):

Message Exchanging Formats means the way in which the client XML structure should look like so that the provider can understand the document. there are 4 MEF's:

1. RPC-Encoded
2. RPC-literal
3. document-encoded (This combination is not recommended by WS-I BP 1.0 & 2.0)
4. document-literal

RPC-encoded is the default MEF for the JAX-RPC API and document-literal is the default MEF for the JAX-WS API